# How to create blackbox functionality testing form

Tags: black-box-testing

I know litte bit bout blackbox functionality testing. But my supervisor asked me to do the form for my system's evaluations. And i don't know how to started it. I need guidances to build the form. Which topics should i include in the form?

Answer (score 0):

Black box testing document covers mainly

1. Action on a particular field
2. Steps to be followed
3. Input
4. Expected Output
5. Result

Please confirm from your Supervisor, whether he/she expects the same from you